# How do I add multiple Array to a JSON object in kotlin for retrofit

Tags: retrofit

**My Code is:**

```
    val objSubBuyNow = JsonObject()

    val arrayProducts = JsonArray()
    for (i in 0 until response.arrList?.size!!) {

        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("strProductId", response.arrList[i]?._id)
        Log.i("kaaa", response.arrList[i]?._id.toString())
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("dblQty", response.arrList[i]?.dblQty)
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("strSize", response.arrList[i]?.strSize)
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("strColor", response.arrList[i]?.strColor)
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("strName", response.arrList[i]?.strName)
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("dblAmount", response.arrList[i]?.dblMRP)
        objSubBuyNow.addProperty("strImageUrl", response.arrList[i]?.strImageUrl)
        arrayProducts.add(objSubBuyNow)
    }

    objBuyNow.add("arrProducts", arrayProducts)
```

But it adds the same array as the loop goes.
Thanks in advance

Comment: add val objSubBuyNow = JsonObject() inside for loop and try

Comment: Thank you so much @Chirag Rayani. Few days I'm working on it to figure it out.

Comment: You can upvote an answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Always..........